# Rails Form in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to put a rails form in a bootstrap modal dialog.  I'd like to use the modal-footer to hold the cancel/submit buttons, but this doesn't seem to work inside the form tag.

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <%= simple_form_for [@state, @search] do |f| %>
     <!-- long form here -->
     <div class="modal-footer">
       <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
       <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
     </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

That's because you are putting the footer inside the body. Use this way instead:

```
<%= simple_form_for [@state, @search] do |f| %>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <!-- long form here -->
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cancel</button>
    <%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn btn-primary' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: but by default the <form> tag generated by simple_form_for have margin-bottom:20px from bootstrap.css which won't look nice

Comment: just got it, unless you add modal-form class to the <form> tag